# Will a thread use an old value passed in?

Tags: java, c#, c++, multithreading, memory

I just thought of this question and couldn't find an answer

If I pass a static non-primitive variable, say X, into a thread which starts at a later time (so one would assume the thread holds a reference to X), is there any possibility that when the thread starts, instead of reading X from memory, it may use the old value of X when X was passed to the thread

or a similar scenario like:

```
thread A runs and writes X = a to RAM, then gets blocked by IO

thread B reads X = a from RAM, queues a unit of work to A, which would use X

thread A resumes and writes X = b to RAM, then it finishes what it had left

...

thread A resumes and runs that unit of work queued to it, which would use X

Is it possible that X would have the value a?
```

If so, is it possible to happen in mainstream languages like C, C++, Java, C# on mainstream platforms? (all versions for jvm for java and all versions for .Net and Mono for C#)?

I would not expect this to happen, but rather curious if it would on any sort-of-popular platforms, causes maybe crazy compiler optimization, caching (always a possibility), extremely cheap hardware etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused. Programs don't read data from memory into... something else (seriously, where do you think it would go?). Its *always* read from memory.

All the time, every time. So no, your scenario is simply not possible. It will always have the updated value.

Quick disclaimer, variables/data can always be cached by the CPU to avoid RAM hits, so if the *hardware* didn't synchronize, this could happen, but its not an issue with the language/runtime. The software concept of "Memory" includes RAM, cache, and Virtual memory.

Comment: yeh I dont think it can happen either, but I am still wondering if there are any crazy compiler optimization, caching, extremely cheap hardware which has weak guarantees could lead to this kind of non-sense situation..

Comment: I am pretty sure this happens in Java actually. I think the virtual machine caches memory unless you give it the volatile keyword. But, I am still convinced that x would equal b in this scenario but if it's static shouldn't there only be one instance of it at any time? Can you change the value of a static variable like that and have it do anything?

Comment: Nevermind, I read up on static variables again. I don't use them often. Unless the threads were creating class objects with that class having x in it might it still equal a.

Comment: "hardware did something horribly wrong" - CPUs are not required to do synchronization of caches unless explicitly told so - it is not "horribly wrong" behavior, but rather one that should be expected.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think what he meant was this wouldn't be a software as written now the issue would be a problem exclusively with the hardware.

Comment: yeh I am mostly a Java guy and I still gets confused. Volatile keyword would take care of the problem in Java for sure, but then Java is the only language can allows the problem to be solved this way......

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, that's what I meant. The software can't control the caching strategy, we *have* to assume our variables are synchronized properly (in terms of cache of course, thread synchronization is still a software issue)

Comment: @MatthewYang all 4 languages you've mention have similar semantic for `volatile` keyword (and to my knowledge none of them *guarantee* cache synchronization for read). Really - lock / use other synchronization objects properly  (or carefully use `interlocked.XXX` operations on Windows ) is the only correct solution.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - the only thing I disagree with is "*horribly wrong*" wording - it allowed and perfectly fine...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Fair enough, removed that wording

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeh they all have volatile but Java is the only one that explicitly specifies that volatile will trigger memory barrier so the variable is always read from memory atomically, C# is close but does not provide strong guarantee (so yeh .Net right now would work as it uses a strong memoiry model, but same thing cant be said about Mono, or any future versions)

Comment: I support locks and agree this problem by itself can be efficiently solved with one lock, I am not trying to invent lock-free code (which I totally should not do unless I am an expert), but if this problem is not something we need to worry about, then we can use one fewer lock and make things easier to get right, too many locks is extremely error prone and hard to debug. So what I am getting here is that we can safely assume we dont need to worry about this problem?

Comment: @MatthewYang Yes, *this* problem will not happen. The other direction is what actually occurs, where X modifies a value *after* Y has stored it off in some other variable, or checked it in an `if` statement, and they get out of sync. *Thats* what you need locks for

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeh those conditions need locks, I was talking about locks here because locks can trigger memory barriers in most languages, as data freshness is the key to this problem but not synchronization or atomicity, a volatile in Java or Thread.MemoryBarrier() in C# would also suffice. But anyway, I guess it makes sense to not worry about it after all..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeh volatile does not really say about memory barriers, it specifies the guarantee that changes to volatile variables are always visible to all threads. However, the explanations on Java's memory barriers sheds light on what is really going on, the trick is that it happens between rw to volatile variables http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the object (concrete fully built) but the state of an Object. So let's say if you have counter within X that constitutes of State and yes if thread a writes to counter then it may happen thread B can't see the changes.